# Using images with webpack react wont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a project that uses webpack and react. I use the file-loader / url-loader to use images with the webpack/react setup. In my react project I do `import Img from '/image/source/image.jpg'` but if then try `<img src={Img}>` the src is a base64 code that is saying `module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "images/code.61e3a3939c2f93f30ac21419625c9a4f.jpg";` and no image is showing. How can I fix this?

## webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require( 'webpack' )
var path = require( 'path' )

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve( __dirname, 'src/client/public' );
var APP_DIR = path.resolve( __dirname, 'src/client/App' );

var config = {
  mode : 'development',
  entry : APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output : {
    path : BUILD_DIR,
    filename : 'bundle.js'
  },

  devServer : {
    publicPath : '/',
    contentBase : './src/client'
  },

  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx|js?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        exclude : /(node_modules)/,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query : {
          presets : [ 'env', 'react' ]
        }
      },

      {
        test : /\.scss|.css$/,
        loaders : [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
      },

      {
        test : /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use : [{
          loader : 'url-loader',
          options : {
            limit : 8000,
            name : 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
          }
        }]
      },

      {
        test : /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use : {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "images/[name].[hash].[ext]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Could you mind show us more detail code?

Comment: It is something you need to work out with your `public-path` and `file-loader` export `name` in Webpack config. You should show us the Webpack configuration you are using now.

Comment: @Up209d I added the config

Comment: @RickGrendel Hey bro, why your `dev-server` have `contentBase` of `src/client`, it is supposed to serve assets from your `BUILD_DIR` since all of your assets processed by Webpack `file loaders` will be delivered there.

Comment: @Up209d the index.html is in that folder and in that index.html I call the bundle.js thats how I learned it :S

Comment: @RickGrendel Use `html-webpack-plugin` my friend, it shall inject your `bundle.js` into the `index.html` and copy the HTML file to the `BUILD_DIR`. You should start the `dev-server` at `BUILD_DIR` anyways

Comment: @Up209d would that solve my problem?

Comment: @RickGrendel If i am not wrong, it will do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest removing the file-loader in your webpack.config.js and only use the url-loader as both plugins work similarly. To my understanding, Webpack processes your images files now using both loaders as you specify for both loaders to be triggered by the following.
`test : /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,`

As images run through both loaders, this is likely why you see `module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "images/code.61e3a3939c2f93f30ac21419625c9a4f.jpg";` for your image source.

Here's what the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) say about the url-loader.

> url-loader works like file-loader, but can return a DataURL if the
>   file is smaller than a byte limit.

Besides that you instruct webpack to use a different file names for the same file extensions which might also create an issue. 
url-loader > `name : 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'`
file-loader > `name: "images/[name].[hash].[ext]"`

I've uploaded this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rscheffers82/SO-webpack-react-images) that you can check out. It loads images as you suggest. Adjust the `limit` setting of the url-loader and check the source to see the url change from a base64 encoded image to an URL.

Answer (score 3):

For Webpack 5 use [type: 'asset/resource'](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#resource-assets)

**webpack.config.js**

```js
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|eot|woff2|woff|ttf|svg)$/i,    
  type: 'asset/resource'
}
```

Comment: IMO this is the most relevant comment, thanks